# How to show/Hide a column conditionally with datatable.net server side processing?

Tags: datatables

I am using datatable 1.10, to generate tables. I use server-side processing. Depending on another variable (status) I want to show or hide an extra column in the table. 
How do I show/hide a column conditionally with datatable.net server side processing?
Here is my code (simplified):

```
 $('#' + id).DataTable({

            dom: "< <'col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'f><'col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'l><'col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding't><'col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'i><'col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'p>>"
        , responsive: true
        , createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) { //this is used to add data- attribute to td element
            $(row).find('td:eq(4)').attr('data-priority', data.Actions[0].action_priority);
        }
        , autoWidth: true //false
        , scrollX: true
        , pageResize: true
        , serverSide: true
        , processing: true
        , pageLength: 100
        , deferRender: true
        , ajax: {
            url: actionURL,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: function (model) {

                model.statusID = statusID ;

            },
        }
        , columnDefs:
          [

            {
                targets: 0,
                createdCell: function (td, data, rowData, row, col) { 

*//this is the part that does not work
                   if (incidentStatusID == 1) {
                      //here show column
                      visible:true;
                   }
                  else{
                       //hide column...
                        visible: false;
                   }
                }

            },*
            {
                targets: 3,
                createdCell: function (td, data, rowData, row, col) { //this is used to add data- attribute to td element
                    $(td).attr('data-priority', data.Actions[0].action_priority);
                }
            }

          ]
```

Maybe I can use an equivalent of `createdRow`, and `createdCell` for the Column? Although I couldn't find one. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html refer this link.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The link did not provide me with a solution directly, but it got me thinking about it in a different way...by trying to hide the column after the table creation, rather than not 'loading' it at all.

Comment: It  is good to have a way to try out something.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this. It is not perfect as it generates the column first and hide it afterward.

This is the column I am trying to hide. I added an ID to it.

```
<th id="controls" data-priority="-1">Controls</th>
```

Then in the datatable code, I added a call to `fnRowCallback`, in order to hide or show the column after the table was generated (this maybe could be improved, so the column would only be generated when needed...). Then I checked the condition (variable 'statusID') to show or hide the column, and hide it with JQuery.

Here is the relevent new piece of code:

```
fnRowCallback: function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull)
{        
      if (statusID== 0) {
          $('#controls').hide();
          $('td:eq(-1)', nRow).hide();
      }
      else {
          $('#controls').show();
      }
}
```